# IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core 2.2 Integrating with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Getting this error

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

I am trying to get `identityserver` and asp.net identity ui to be in one project.

Followed this http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html#new-project-for-asp-net-identity article to get the needed extra code.
I did the following steps

1. Create a ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC App, Single Account authentication
2. **Tested it to make sure it works, registered a user, logged in, all works well.**
3. Added nuget package `IdentityServer4.AspnetIdentity`
4. Added Config.cs file below

   ```
   public static class Config
   {
   public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
   {
       return new List<IdentityResource>
       {
           new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
           new IdentityResources.Profile(),
           new IdentityResources.Email(),
       };
   }
   public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
   {
       return new List<ApiResource>
       {
           new ApiResource("eventsapi", "Events Api")
       };
   }
   public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
   {
       return new List<Client>
       {
           new Client
           {
               ClientId = "client",

               // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

               // secret for authentication
               ClientSecrets =
               {
                   new Secret("secret".Sha256())
               },

               // scopes that client has access to
               AllowedScopes = { "eventsapi" }
           }
       };
   }
   }
   ```
5. Added ApplicationUser.cs

   ```
   public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
   {
   }
   ```
6. Modified Startup.cs (commented code is the generated)

   ```
     public class Startup
      {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
         Configuration = configuration;
      }

   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
       {

           options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
           options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
       });

       services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
       /*
       services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
           .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
       */
       //REPLACED ABOVE
       services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();




       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

       //ADDDED
       services.AddIdentityServer()
           .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
           .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
           .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
           .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
           .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
           .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

   }


   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
       }
       else
       {
           app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
       }

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();
       app.UseStaticFiles();
       app.UseCookiePolicy();

       //app.UseAuthentication();
       //REPLACED ABOVE
       app.UseIdentityServer();
       app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: You'll have this code somewhere in your project (either in a controller or perhaps a view): `UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager`. Find all of those and change them to `UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error, try to change `IdentityUser` in `Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml`.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

And then, you need to register `AddDefaultUI` which is used to handle identity area request to the action in `Startup.cs` like

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```